# Объединение данных в postgres без повторений

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

У меня есть несколько таблиц, данные которых нужно объединить. В первой таблице хранятся все подписчики всех каналов телеграма, таблица `users` (запись про одного пользователя может быть только 1).

Во второй таблице источник вступления, таблица `urls users` (записей про одного пользователя может быть много, в зависимости от того, сколько раз он приходил и уходил), так скажем, история входов и уходов.

В третьей таблице хранятся каналы, где бот-админ для аналитики собирает данные, таблица `channels`.

В четвёртой таблице есть ссылки каналов, таблица `urls channels` (источники для вступления).

```
users:
id | user_id | username | first_name

urls_users:
id | user_id | url_id | is_sub | datetime_subscribed | datetime unsubscribed

url_id это id из

channels:
id | channel_id | name | description | datetime_added

channels_urls:
id | channel_id | name | url_value | datetime_added
```

И мне нужно всё это показывать как одну таблицу:

```
user id | username | first name | дата последнего выхода | дата последнего входа | каналы на которые подписан | последний источник входа (ссылка) | предпоследний источник входа (ссылка)
```

У меня есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS user_id, 
  u.username, 
  u.first_name, 
  cc.name AS subscribed_channels, 
  cu.url_value AS last_entry_url
FROM 
  users u 
LEFT JOIN 
  urls_users uu ON u.user_id = uu.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
  channels c ON uu.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
  channels_urls cu ON c.channel_id = cu.channel_id 
LEFT JOIN channels cc ON cu.channel_id = cu.channel_id
GROUP BY 
  u.id, c.id, cu.id, cc.id;
```

Но тут выводится очень много строк, с повторениями пользователей. Но у каждого дубликата различается хотя бы 1 ячейка, допустим, канал другой или же источник входа другой.

Хочется, чтобы каналы и источник входа собрались по 1 ячейке, то есть, чтобы не было повторов пользователей (к примеру, в столбце каналов через запятую перечислялись каналы). Так же у меня в запросе не сделаны дата входа и выхода.

Буду рад за любую помощь, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что проблема в этом месте:

```
FROM  
  users u  
LEFT JOIN  
  urls_users uu ON u.user_id = uu.user_id  
LEFT JOIN  
  channels c ON uu.user_id = u.user_id
```

Попробуйте указать столбец из стаблицы chanels

```
FROM  
  users u  
LEFT JOIN  
  urls_users uu ON u.user_id = uu.user_id  
LEFT JOIN  
  channels c ON uu.user_id = c.user_id
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).